# Precise definition of the limit variation

Tags: calculus, limits

In most textbooks, I have seen that for
$$
\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty
$$
The precise definition of limit is that:

> For every $M>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$
> 0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow f(x)>M $$

I have seen someone using a slightly modified version of this:

> For every $M>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $$
> 0<|x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow f(x)\geq M $$

Is the second version (the one with equality) correct? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both true (equivalent), though possibly not with the same $\delta$. The second version gives the suggestion that f(x) might equal M, which may not happen if f is a discontinuous function (one with jumps in its values). On balance the first version is preferred.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are both correct.  They are actually equivalent.  Clearly the first implies the second.  The second implies the first because given $M>0$ you may choose $M'=2M>M$ and apply the second definition to $M'$.  Then the first statement holds with $M$.